# battery bank mixing and draw

Tags: battery-storage

I have a few questions regarding battery packs.

1. Is it OK to mix 2 sets of old batteries together, ie 2 are 75Ah and other 2 are 70Ah, they all came out of a mobility scooter and weren't getting the range anymore, the 70Ah ones are heavy and larger
2. Is the max draw currant the same as max charge currant as that's all information I have. Does it refer to 1 battery in a bank in parallel
3. If so does that mean the lowest batteries max charge current

Comment: It is never a good idea to mix battery capacities. Charge and discharge limits are very different things, if you don't know what they are, you can't safely do anything with the batteries. It will be clear in the battery datasheet what they refer to. If it isn't, you need to ask the supplier. If you can't get information, don't use these batteries.

Comment: If the 70 Ah batteries are significantly larger and heavier than the 75 Ah batteries, they are likely different chemistry, having different actual voltages (even if they are both nominally 12 volt) and different charging requirements.  Mixing two different battery types in a bank may be hazardous, and probably won't work well.

Comment: thks but what im getting at is they all at aprox 50% capcity

Comment: and both say agm